# Choose one name based on ID

Tags: tableau-api

My data has 2 columns: ID and Name. Due to renaming, each ID might contain 2 distinct names. How shall I ask Tableau to use only the latest name?

For example, the old name version contained "apple" as a specific word. The new version names contain "orange". I assume it might be useful to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the data is in below format and you want to fetch the latest date's  name corresponding to ID:

```
ID  Name    Date
11  AA      7/17/2017
11  BB      7/18/2017
11  CC      7/19/2017
12  LLL     7/17/2017
13  MMM     7/17/2017
14  PPP     7/22/2017
12  KKKK    7/23/2017
30  RRRRR   7/24/2017
```

I would suggest you to

- Create calculated field `isLatest` having definition as `[Date] =
  {fixed[ID]: max([Date])}`
- Drag `ID` and `MDY(Date)` to 'Rows' and `Name` in 'Text' Marks
- Drag `islatest` to 'Filters' and select `TRUE`

The final result would be:

```
ID  Date    
11  7/19/2017   CC
12  7/23/2017   KKKK
13  7/17/2017   MMM
14  7/22/2017   PPP
30  7/24/2017   RRRRR
```

*Pls don't forget to let us know if it helped :)*

Comment: Nice function! Thank you!

Comment: any idea how to make it when the Name can't be in the text field? I have a measure in the text.

Comment: Isn't `ATTR([Measure_Name])` in 'Text' Marks working?